# SQL - Remove pattern from varchar string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

One of our applications was appending notes to the end of one of our columns, we have now removed this from the app and wish to remove existing from the data.
I have a pattern within Varchar (2000) String :

- Credit received 08/11/2019 **record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 08/11/2019)**
- Request removal of ship to adress **record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 20/09/2019)**

Points to note:

- Pattern can be anywhere within the string
- Pattern can occur multiple time within the string
- Username Varies
- Date Changes

Not sure what the best approach to this would be?

Comment: So it the "pattern" always "record undleted by ({USERNAME} @ {date})" If so, you can achieve that quite easily without pattern matching, but string matching (using `CHARINDEX`). If not, then what other "patterns" are there? SQL Server's forté is *not* string manipulation, so if you're going to back this complex (which is isn't at the moment), then the best approach would be use a language that supports REGEX.

Comment: The fact the pattern can appear multiple times, however, is a "problem". Something like that would easily be better suited for pattern replacement; which T-SQL doesn't natively support.

Comment: if you add a `regexReplace` function in `CLR`, this becomes as easy as a single update table

Comment: @Larnu - There are no other patterns as such, there could be lots of other text - forgot to mention that this is on a SQL 2005 Server. But yes, "the record undleted by ({USERNAME} @ {date})" is the consistent pattern.
In regards to it appearing multiple times - I suppose i could run the script multiple times?

Comment: *"forgot to mention that this is on a SQL 2005 Server"* That is something you should have mentioned at the get go, in your tags; that literally throws every idea I had out the window. You *need* to get that 5 years end of life product updated, ASAP. I can only suggest trying to find a CLR function that works on 2005. Good luck with that... Using SQL Server 2005 is both a security risk and a huge limiting factor here.

Comment: A simple UDF scanning the string and replace it combined to the advanced LIKE will do a good and quick job

Comment: The LIKE can be this one : LIKE '%record undeleted by (% @ [0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])%'

Comment: How would you determine start, and end, of multiple "patterns" in the same string and replace them, @SQLpro ? This just finds the relevant rows. It's been a long time since I used SQL Server 2005, but I recall that there's a lot of things we take for granted since 2008/2012 that is missing in 2005.

Comment: SQLpro - Thanks, will give that a go.
Larnu - will ensure I mention that going forward, we are working on deprecating these legacy systems, a long project we are working on going back a few years. Not easy with app 25+ years old with source code missing! Fully aware of 2005 issues.

Answer (score 1):

As I say, with an UDF like this one :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_REMOVE_RECORD_UNDELETE (@ROW VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(max) = '';
   DECLARE @POSITION INT = CHARINDEX('record undeleted by (', @ROW);
   WHILE @POSITION > 0
   BEGIN
      SET @RESULT = @RESULT + LEFT(@ROW, @POSITION - 1);
      SET @ROW = RIGHT(@ROW, LEN(@ROW) - CHARINDEX(')', @ROW, @POSITION + 1));
      SET @POSITION = CHARINDEX('record undeleted by (', @ROW);
   END
   RETURN @RESULT;
END;
GO
```

The modification is easy combining to the LIKE :

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST_STRING_TST
(TST_ID       INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 TST_STRING   VARCHAR(8000));
GO

INSERT INTO T_TEST_STRING_TST VALUES
(' noting '),
('Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 08/11/2019) bla bla bla'),
('anyting record undeleted ()'),
('Request removal of ship to adress record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 20/09/2019)bolo bolo'),
('Request removal of ship to adress record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 20/09/2019)bolo bolo record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 11/12/2020) bolo bolo'),
('anyting record undeleted ( @ 08/11/2019)');

UPDATE T_TEST_STRING_TST
SET    TST_STRING =  dbo.F_REMOVE_RECORD_UNDELETE(TST_STRING)
WHERE  TST_STRING LIKE '%record undeleted by (% @ [0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])%';
```

For SQL 2005, you must rewrite the UDF as :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_REMOVE_RECORD_UNDELETE (@ROW VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(max);
   SET @RESULT = '';
   DECLARE @POSITION INT;
   SET POSITION = CHARINDEX('record undeleted by (', @ROW)
   WHILE @POSITION > 0
   BEGIN
      SET @RESULT = @RESULT + LEFT(@ROW, @POSITION - 1);
      SET @ROW = RIGHT(@ROW, LEN(@ROW) - CHARINDEX(')', @ROW, @POSITION + 1));
      SET @POSITION = CHARINDEX('record undeleted by (', @ROW);
   END
   RETURN @RESULT;
END;
GO
```

Comment: This has worked as needed. i needed to tweak slightly to get round the 'Cannot assign a default value to a local variable in SQL' error (2005)

Comment: Will it work in case you have two occurrences to be deleted from same string (like the 5 row for table T_TEST_STRING_TST)?

Comment: @AhmedHuq yes, test it !

Answer (score 0):

You were told already, that SQL Server v2005 is something you really should change.

I'm not sure if this works with v2005, no chance to test this anywhere, but you can give it a try:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl(YourString) VALUES
 ('Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (USERNAME @ 08/11/2019) Some more to come record undeleted by (SOMEONEELSE @ 10/11/2019)')
,('Request removal of ship to adress record undeleted by (ONEMORE @ 20/09/2019)');

SELECT t.ID
      ,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,' record undeleted by','<!--'),')','-->') AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @tbl t;
```

The idea in short:

- We use `CAST()` and some string methods to

  - transform this into XML and to
  - wrap your unwanted text as XML comment.
- Now we can use `.value()` to read the XML's content. The comment is omitted.

One intermediate result looks like this

```xml
Credit received 08/11/2019<!-- (USERNAME @ 08/11/2019--> Some more to come<!-- (SOMEONEELSE @ 10/11/2019-->
```

You can see, that anything unwanted is within the XML comment.

Hint 1: Using the `)` as replacement character is - assumingly - not enough. But it might suffice to re-replace the `-->` with `)` in the resulting string.

Hint 2: Starting with v2008 there is `STUFF()` you could replace (=overwrite) a given number of characters after the `@` with the comment closing tag. In v2005 you will have to loop...

Hint 3: If the *immediate* `CAST().value()` syntax is not supported in v2005, try to run this without the `.value()`. You can proceed in two steps then...

**UPDATE**

For my "Hint 1" this will help:

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,     REPLACE(
       CAST(REPLACE(
            REPLACE(YourString,' record undeleted by','<!--')
                                                     ,')','-->') AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                     ,'-->',')')
FROM @tbl t;
```

Comment: From the table test I post, the result is uncorrecte leaving : "anyting record undeleted (-->" and "anyting record undeleted ( @ 08/11/2019-->". Another point is the horrible cost of using XML !

Comment: @SQLpro, please take a closer look... In your sample you sometimes miss the "by". That's why some results return incorrectly. You might use my code without the "by" in `REPLACE()` as a quick check. Furthermore in my "Hint 1" I suggest to use another `REPLACE()` in cases where a closing bracket might be translated to `-->`. And - last but not least - the OP informs us, that this is a *one-timer*. So performance does not matter...

Comment: @SQLpro, btw: A scalar function calling a WHILE-loop won't be fast as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with 2nd attempt:**
This time I have created the following UDF which tries to find out the username and based on that replaces the pattern. As it is a UDF, it works for multiple occurrences of the pattern. I do not think speed-wise it is a good solution.

```
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.test(@input varchar(2000))
RETRUNS varchar(2000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
@start_pos int = 0
,@end_pos1 int = 0
,@r varchar(2000) = ''
,@r1 varchar(2000) = ''
,@to_del varchar(2000) = ''
,@user_name varchar(2000) = ''

set @r = @input

WHILE patindex('%record undeleted by_(%_@_[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])%', @r) > 0
BEGIN
    set @start_pos = 0; set @r1 = ''; set @user_name = ''; set @end_pos1 = 0 set @to_del = '';
    
    set @start_pos = len('record undeleted by_(') + patindex('%record undeleted by_(%_@_[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])%', @r) 
    set @r1 = substring(@r, @start_pos, len(@r))
    set @user_name = ltrim(rtrim(substring(@r1, 1, patindex('%_@_[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])%', @r1))))
    set @end_pos1 = LEN(@user_name) + 15
    set @to_del = 'record undeleted by ('+ ltrim(rtrim(substring(@r1, 1, @end_pos1)))
    set @r = replace(@r, @to_del, '')
END
    RETURN @r
END

GO
```

Following is the code for test table and SELECT statement using the UDF.

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity(1,1)
,dscr varchar(2000)
)

insert into @t(dscr)
select 'Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (@ahmedhuq @ 08/11/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (group1\user1 @ 20/09/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (group1\user1 @ 20/09/2019) and the quick brown fox' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (dir1\user2 @ 20/09/2019) and Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (@ahmedhuq @ 08/11/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted' 

select * , dbo.test(dscr)
from @t where dscr like '%record undeleted by_(%_@_[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])%'
```

The result comes as:

[image]

**Ignore attempt 1:**
The script below can't be used as working solution. It works OK if the pattern occurs only once. For multiple occurrences of the pattern, the data gets corrupted!

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity(1,1)
,dscr varchar(2000)
)

insert into @t(dscr)
select 'Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (@ahmedhuq @ 08/11/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (group1\user1 @ 20/09/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (group1\user1 @ 20/09/2019) and the quick brown fox' union

select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted by (dir1\user2 @ 20/09/2019) and Credit received 08/11/2019 record undeleted by (@ahmedhuq @ 08/11/2019)' union
select 'Request removal of ship to address record undeleted' 

select * from @t
where dscr like '%record undeleted by_(%_@___/__/____)%'

;with a as
(
    select * 
    ,patindex( '%record undeleted by_(%_@___/__/____)%', dscr) as start_pos
    ,patindex( reverse('%record undeleted by_(%_@___/__/____)%'), reverse(dscr)) as end_pos_reverse
    ,len(dscr) - patindex( reverse('%record undeleted by_(%_@___/__/____)%'), reverse(dscr)) + 2 as end_pos
    from 
    @t
)
,a1 as
(
    select *
    ,end_pos - start_pos as start_end_len
    from
    a
)
,a2 as
(
    select 
    *,substring(dscr, start_pos, start_end_len) replace_str
    from
    a1
)
select
*
,replace(dscr, replace_str, '') as result1
from
a2
```

Comment: `STUFF()` was introduced not before v2008... (afaik).

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo for pointing that out. I have modified the script to use substring and replace, kept CTEs to show steps. Unfortunately, it will not work for multi patterns and not only that, it will corrupt the data. So looking....

Comment: I have added my 2nd attempt as a UDF and this seems to be working OK.